# How to execute Button Command with Parameter without providing the Parameter when called in the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, winui-3

I am new to MVVM pattern and I just wanted to ask what is the best way to "click" or execute a button command that has a command parameter of contentdialog from the ViewModel.

Example code:
View

```
<Button Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.OpenContentDialog}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DialogBox}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3">Open Dialog</Button>

<ContentDialog x:Name="DialogBox"
           PrimaryButtonText="OK" IsPrimaryButtonEnabled="{Binding PrimaryButtonEnabled}"
           CloseButtonText="Cancel">
                                <ContentDialog.TitleTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Text="Dialog"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ContentDialog.TitleTemplate>
...
```

ViewModel

```
 public RelayCommand<object> OpenContentDialog => new RelayCommand<object>((dialog) => { SortDialog(dialog); });
```

I want to call the OpenContentDialog command in another ViewModel method like this:

```
OpenContentDialog.Execute(); //needs the parameter
```

I have tried passing the actual ContentDialog as a ViewModel Object, it works but I am not sure if that violates the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Commands are generally not supposed to be called by Code, though of course it's possible. Maintaining a Control-Instance in ViewModel seems not to be a good practice. Could you provide details on ``SortDialog(object param)``. What is it doing?

Comment: sure it basically just shows the content dialog with the ShowAsync and waits the contentdialogresult

Comment: So as you press the button, the dialog isn't shown actually...? Or are those elements not in the same XAML? I admit, I'm not using winui yet, I'm on WPF. From that point of view, the ``DialogBox`` you are passing as CommandParameter would be part of the Visual containing the button :-)

Comment: Nope, the relay command tied on the button actually shows the content dialog when clicked. The thing that I want to implement is to programmatically call that button click in the ViewModel or even better, show the content dialog without the use of the button click...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the command expects a `ContentDialog` to be passed as an argument, your two options are to either create such a `ContentDialog` programmatically before you call `Execute` or get a reference to an already existing dialog:

```
OpenContentDialog.Execute(
    new ContentDialog() { PrimaryButtonText = "OK", IsPrimaryButtonEnabled = true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you are wanting mvvm and winui 3, there is a very good how to found at https://xamlbrewer.wordpress.com/2022/02/07/building-a-master-detail-page-with-winui-3-and-mvvm/

It includes community toolkit icons for add, delete, or edit. You will probably like his other posts and examples in winui 3 as well

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32245836)